# algorithm: a geometric shape may contain another shape

Tags: algorithm, geometry

we have an algorithm that creates a rectangular shape and a second shape with an number indeterminate of side and which can have internal shapes (donut style for example) and the goal is creates an algorithm that will see if the rectangle can be contained in the geometric shape.

the program is in python and it uses shapely. At first we test the areas and if the area of ​​the rectangle can be contained in the shape we just put it in the center and we test. If it don't enter we are doing  a rotation of one degree (for example) and continue the test.
after 180 degrees we stop the rotation and move it from 1 cemtimeter (for example) in spriral shape (to make all the positions around the center of gravity of the geometric shape).

The program works well but for some form it is relatively slow (several minutes of calculation) not being a i not a professional in trigonometry I ask you for help to speed up the treatment.

Do you have any suggestions?

thank you.

exemple to slow:

http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/51/5/1545390818-3dadvwcbpzmewfdbzrm7.png

http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/51/5/1545390818-htadvwcbpzmewfdbzrq7.png

http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/51/5/1545390818-ojadvwcbpzmewfdbzqg6.png

http://image.noelshack.com/fichiers/2018/51/5/1545390818-3dadvwcbpzmewfdbzrm7.png

Comment: Is outer polygon convex?

Comment: yes it's possible!

Comment: I personally can't think of any other algorithms than just plain brute-force, but I think it doesn't make sense to try out all positions for the shape. You can just stick one of the corners on your polygon. It is guaranteed to be optimal and if there is an answer, then it can always be placed in a way that it touches the polygon with one corner, isn't it? I can be wrong

Answer (score 0):

We can find if rotated rectangle fits into **convex** polygon with sliding points approach.

Place one corner (let A) of rectangle in some polygon vertex and put another corner B on edge right to that vertex (or next edge if rectangle edge is too long). Slide A right until A or B meets polygon vertex. Check whether trajectories of C and D intersect polygon edges. These trajectories might be straight or something like cycloide (if B slides on another edgr than A). Repeat for the next piece while A or B meets the next vertex. If failed, check also other placement - B-C edge.

Sadly, this approach does not work for concave polygons.